# Download de imagem da memória do servidor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho um projeto Asp.Net MVC onde gero uma imagem em memória e gostaria de fazer o download.

Veja um trecho do código:

```
Image imagem = default(Image);

using (Bitmap b = new Bitmap(bitmapWidth, bitmapHeight))
{
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b))
    {
        g.Clear(Color.Red);

        var font = new Font("Arial", 50, FontStyle.Bold);
        g.DrawString("Stackoverflow", font, Brushes.White, posicaoX, posicaoY);
    }

    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        b.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        imagem = Image.FromStream(stream);
    }
}

using (System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    client.DownloadFile(imagem); // Não sei bem como posso fazer o Download.
}
```

Comment: Crie uma action para fazer download.... qual versao do MVC?

Comment: O que você quer dizer com "fazer o download"? O *download* deveria ser feito em um outro servidor. Seria trazer de outro lugar pra cá. Será que você que gravar no servidor? Gravar em outro servidor? Ou seja, fzer *upload*? Quer usar em algum lugar?

Comment: Esse código está rodando em um servidor, só queria baixar o arquivo para o cliente. É exatamente o que está sendo feito na resposta. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No seu *Controller*, crie uma *Action* assim:

```
    public FileResult Imagem()
    {
        /* Carregue o stream antes. */
        return File(stream, "image/jpeg");
    }
```

Ou ainda, adaptando sua lógica:

```
public FileResult Imagem()
{
    Image imagem = default(Image);

    using (Bitmap b = new Bitmap(bitmapWidth, bitmapHeight))
    {
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b))
        {
            g.Clear(Color.Red);

            var font = new Font("Arial", 50, FontStyle.Bold);
            g.DrawString("Stackoverflow", font, Brushes.White, posicaoX, posicaoY);
        }

        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            b.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            imagem = Image.FromStream(stream);
            return File(stream.ToArray(), "image/jpeg");
        }   
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT**

Não sei o que está fechando o *stream*, segundo seu comentário, mas eu tentaria carregar outro *stream* pra devolver, assim:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    imagem.Save(ms,ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    return File(ms.ToArray(), "image/jpeg");
}
```

Comment: haha... muito obrigado fera! Só estou aguardando passar os 10 min pra poder aceitar sua resposta.

Comment: Só tem uma coisinha no `return` pra corrigir... `stream` está fora do contexto...

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues Verdade. Editei.

Comment: Só uma dúvida... Porque tenho que retornar `stream` ao invés de `imagem`?

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues Porque o método `File` é assim: `protected internal FileContentResult File(byte[] fileContents, string contentType);`. Como você já tem um `stream` pronto, já tem um *byte array*.

Comment: Dei uma olhada aqui, é isso mesmo... Mais uma vez muito obrigado!

Comment: Só mais um probleminha... Eu não posso mudar o tipo de retorno onde está esse trecho (atualmente ele retorna ActionResult). Estou usando MVC 4, e ao tentar usar `return File(stream, "image/jpeg");` dentro do `using` um erro é gerado:
_Não é possível acessar um fluxo fechado. 

Descrição: Ocorreu uma exceção sem tratamento durante a execução da atual solicitação da Web. Examine o rastreamento de pilha para obter mais informações sobre o erro e onde foi originado no código. 

Detalhes da Exceção: System.ObjectDisposedException: Não é possível acessar um fluxo fechado._

Comment: Estranho fechar o *stream* assim. Coloquei uma sugestão.

Comment: o @Randrade me deu [um apoio aqui no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/25825512#25825512).